# NSMutableAttributedString: Ambiguous use of 'init(string:attributes:)'

Tags: swift, swift4.2, nsmutableattributedstring

I am trying to run the code I wrote some months ago. Now I use Swift 4.2/Xcode 10.1. I get the error **Ambiguous use of 'init(string:attributes:)'** on

```
let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "", attributes: [:])
```

I also use [SwiftyAttributes 4.3.0](https://github.com/eddiekaiger/SwiftyAttributes/tree/v4.3.0). [Here](https://github.com/eddiekaiger/SwiftyAttributes/blob/v4.3.0/SwiftyAttributes/Sources/common/NSAttributedString%2BSwiftyAttributes.swift) I found 
`public convenience init(string str: String, attributes: [Attribute])`, but I cannot understand why Swift wants to call this function.

How can I solve this issue? Is it necessary to update SwiftyAttributes?

Comment: I don't get any error from that line when copied into a Swift 4.2 playground in Xcode 10.1.

Comment: Works for me too. Maybe clean and build. Seems someone else also came across this [here](https://github.com/delba/TextAttributes/pull/7) but that was quite a while back. Anyways, try `NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")`

Comment: @staticVoidMan Thanks. I use SwiftyAttributes 4.3.0 and I cannot understand why this version does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `init` method declared in SwiftyAttributes 4.3.0:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    public convenience init(string str: String, attributes: [Attribute]) {
        self.init(string: str, attributes: dictionary(from: attributes))
    }
}
```

In SwiftyAttributes 5.0.0 this method was renamed to `public convenience init(string str: String, swiftyAttributes attrs: [Attribute])`. Therefore, I updated SwiftyAttributes to solve the problem. See [this link](https://github.com/eddiekaiger/SwiftyAttributes/issues/29) for more detail about the fix added to SwiftyAttributes 5.0.0.